# Speed up creating a list of PL/SQL function/procedure dependencies

Tags: regex, oracle, function, plsql, regexp-substr

We are creating a list of functions and procedures used when executing a restricted version of a piece of software in PL/SQL. Our process is slow though, and we want to find a faster way of finding function or procedure calls made within a given function or procedure's code. The words function and procedure are used interchangeably throughout this post...

Our current process:

1) Get the function source code of given function in table using regexp_substr:

```
l_function_source := REGEXP_SUBSTR(FUNCTION|PROCEDURE)(\s)+'|| i_function_name ||'(\s|\()+(.)+END(\s)+'|| i_function_name||'(\s)*(;)'
```

2) For each word (slowness!) of the function source we look for 'foreign' function calls (e.g. package_name.function_name(param1,param2..)), remove them, and then scan for local function calls (e.g. function_name(param1,param2..)). Each time we find a new function/procedure, we add it to a table of function names.

Ideally I'd like to get a list of dependencies for each function, much like you do a table. E.g.:

```
SELECT referenced_name 
FROM USER_DEPENDENCIES 
WHERE TYPE IN ('FUNCTION','PROCEDURE') 
AND NAME = i_function_name ;
```

This way we could loop through the list, querying each function/procedure name and adding their dependents to the list without having to rely on regexps and looping through each word. Sadly this doesn't seem to exist. Any suggestions or comments would be highly appreciated.

Fe

Comment: `user_dependencies` should show the functions/procedures/packages that are used by your function. You might want to query the "other direction" as well: `where referenced_name = i_function_name`

Comment: Are you looking for dependencies *within* a package, function, or procedure?  Have you looked at [PL/Scope](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_plscope.htm)?

Comment: We tried running this statement:
`SELECT * FROM USER_DEPENDENCIES WHERE type='FUNCTION' and REFERENCED_TYPE = 'FUNCTION';`
But it returns an empty result sadly. Is there anything I can do to improve the user_dependencies table?
@JonHeller we are looking for the dependencies within a function or procedure. By Procedure/Function I mean procedures or functions declared within our package. We are trying to create a 'Lite' version of a full application by just including the code used for a specific segment of the application. Thanks for your comments though!

Comment: Try using all_dependencies to query your SQL.

Comment: Thanks @AvrajitRoy. Although that does return functions referenced by functions, it mainly lists SYS functions, which aren't of interest for us. Pity they don't include the same functionality for user-defined functions! Would've saved us a load of time.